# Find minimum peak elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

**Question:** Given an array `numbers = {2, 7, 8, 5, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4}`. Check the below conditions, both the conditions should be satisfied.

1. `a[i] > a[i-1]` or `if first element a[i] > a[i+1]`
2. `a[i] > a[i+1]` or if `last element a[lastelement] > a[lastelement - 1]`

Therefore:

- **1st Iteration** - 8, 6, 9 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 6. New arr {2, 7, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 4}. Output Arr - {6}
- **2nd Iteration** - 8, 9 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 8. New arr {2, 7, 5, 1, 3, 9, 4}. Output Arr - {6, 8}
- **3rd Iteration** - 7, 9 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 7. New arr {2, 5, 1, 3, 9, 4}. Output Arr - {6, 7, 8}
- **4th Iteration** - 5, 9 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 5. New arr {2, 1, 3, 9, 4}. Output Arr - {6, 7, 8, 5}
- **5th Iteration** - 2, 9 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 2. New arr {1, 3, 9, 4}. Output Arr - {6, 7, 8, 5, 2}
- **6th Iteration** - 9 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 9. New arr {1, 3, 4}. Output Arr - {6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 9}
- **7th Iteration** - 4 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 4. New arr {1, 3}. Output Arr - {6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4}
- **8th Iteration** - 3 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 3. New arr {1}. Output Arr - {6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3}
- **9th Iteration** - 1 are peak values. Remove the smallest ele. Remove 1. New arr {1}. Output Arr - {6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 1}

**Output:** `{6, 8, 7, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 1}`

My solution is working but I am looking for optimized solution. Please let me know.

Here is my code:

```
public int[] findMinimumPeaks(int[] arr){
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);
        int[] output = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i: arr)
            list1.add(i);
        
        for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
            int minIndex = minimumPeakElement(list1);
            output[i] = list1.get(minIndex);
            list1.remove(minIndex);
        }
        return output;
    }
    
    public int minimumPeakElement(List<Integer> list1){
        int minIndex = 0, peakStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE, peakEnd = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int peak = Integer.MAX_VALUE, minPeak = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        
        if(list1.size() >= 2){
            if(list1.get(0) > list1.get(1)) peakStart = list1.get(0);
            if(list1.get(list1.size() - 1) > list1.get(list1.size() - 2)) peakEnd = list1.get(list1.size() - 1);
            if(peakStart < peakEnd){
                minPeak = peakStart;
                minIndex = 0;
            }
            else if(peakEnd < peakStart){
                minPeak = peakEnd;
                minIndex = list1.size() - 1;
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=1; i<list1.size() - 1; i++){
            if(list1.get(i) > list1.get(i + 1) && list1.get(i) > list1.get(i-1)) peak = list1.get(i);
            if(peak < minPeak){
                minPeak = peak;
                minIndex = i;
            } 
        }
        return minIndex;
    }
```

Comment: For a review of working code, you can post on our sister site [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea how to optimize asymptotic complexity.

Use single pass over elements of your initial array to split it into "up-down" "slopes" or "hills", i.e. subsequence of elements in ascending order, followed by subsequence in descending order.
[image: slopes]

Store these slopes in the following datastructure:

```
val slopes = MinPriorityQueue<Slope>()

class Slope(
 var first: Int, // first element of the slope
 var last: Int,   // last element of the slope
 var peak: Int,   // max or peak element
 var els: MaxPriorityQueue<Int>(),  // all elements of the slope
 var prev: Slope?,    // link to the previous slope in the list or null if first
 var next: Slope?     // link to the next slope in the list or null if last
)
```

Slopes should be comparable by their `peak` value.

Now, having this data structure, you can `poll` the slope that has minimal peak value in `O(log(N))`.  After you polled the slope, you should update the slope by removing it's peak element (i.e. poll `els`, then update `first`, `last`, `peak`), also, slope might become eligible to be merged with the previous or next slope:

[image: after slopes were merged]

Admittedly, this solution is not an easy one, having a lot of things to maintain and large number of corner cases. However, it's much better in terms of asymptotic complexity.

- Initial data structure build: `O(n log(n))`
- Polling elements while maintaining slopes:  `O(n log (n))`
- Overall complexity:  `O(n log(n))`

Notes:

1. One of the corner cases, if array can have duplicate elements, then inner priority queue (`els`) becomes `MaxPriorityQueue<Pair<Int,Int>>`, i.e. you need to store the number of potentially duplicate elements along with the element value.
2. `MinPriorityQueue` and `MaxPriorityQueue` is an abstract [heap-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) data structure with min and max element at the head respectively.  Can be implemented with [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in java